# Access a XAML control defined in a ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I am using Xamarin forms and in XAML i am trying to change the **Image** property of the `PlayButton (Button)` defined in the `ControlTemplate` in the App.xaml. I cannot seem to access the `Button` control within `App.xaml.cs` file in the code behind. Does anyone know how to get access to the button or know how I could change the Image property?

```
<Application.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="PageTemplate">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
          <Button x:Name="PlayButton" />
      </Stacklayout>
   </ControlTemplate>
 <ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: A template is a *template*. There is no `Button` to access until the template has actually been applied to some element. You don't change a template that you have defined in your XAML programmatically. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mm8 I am planning to use this as a page Template, the `button` will be a play function for every page, the button is a play/pause(With relevant images). In the click event, I plan to alternate the images on the `button` control. So now on the click event located in `App.xaml.cs`, I cannot access the button to further change the image. Where can i access this button to achieve this and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template is a *template*. There is no `Button` to access until the template has actually been applied to some element.

> ... So now on the click event located in `App.xaml.cs`, I cannot access the `button` to further change the image. Where can access this `button` to achieve this and how?

You could cast the sender argument in the event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    //...
}
```